# hibernate : Too much contention on sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

I am using hibernate for Apache Derby DB. When I am running my application first time it is getting paused at session.save(object) and not proceeding further but when I am building my application second time it is throwing error below.

StackTrace is as below:-

```
10:05:42,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not extract ResultSet

10:05:42,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:92)

10:05:42,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)

10:05:42,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)

10:05:42,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)

10:05:42,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)

10:05:42,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:122)

10:05:42,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.generate(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:73)

10:05:42,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)

10:05:42,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)

10:05:42,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)

10:05:42,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)

10:05:42,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)

10:05:42,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)

10:05:42,133 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)

10:05:42,133 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)

10:05:42,133 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)

10:05:42,133 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at rest.food.ordering.dao.FoodOrderingDaoImpl.saveServingLocation(FoodOrderingDaoImpl.java:31)

10:05:42,133 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at rest.food.ordering.service.FoodOrderingServiceImpl.saveServingLocations(FoodOrderingServiceImpl.java:30)

10:05:42,133 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at rest.food.ordering.controller.FoodOrderingController.saveServingLocations(FoodOrderingController.java:26)

10:05:42,133 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

10:05:42,133 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

10:05:42,133 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

10:05:42,134 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

10:05:42,134 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)

10:05:42,134 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)

10:05:42,134 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)

10:05:42,134 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)

10:05:42,135 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)

10:05:42,135 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)

10:05:42,135 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)

10:05:42,135 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)

10:05:42,135 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)

10:05:42,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)

10:05:42,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)

10:05:42,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)

10:05:42,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

10:05:42,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

10:05:42,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

10:05:42,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

10:05:42,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

10:05:42,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:05:42,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

10:05:42,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

10:05:42,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:05:42,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

10:05:42,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

10:05:42,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

10:05:42,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

10:05:42,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

10:05:42,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

10:05:42,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:05:42,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

10:05:42,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:05:42,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:05:42,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)

10:05:42,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)

10:05:42,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

10:05:42,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)

10:05:42,140 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)

10:05:42,140 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:792)

10:05:42,140 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

10:05:42,140 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

10:05:42,140 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

10:05:42,140 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Too much contention on sequence SERVING_LOCATION_SEQUENCE. This is probably caused by an uncommitted scan of the SYS.SYSSEQUENCES catalog. Do not query this catalog directly. Instead, use the SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_PEEK_AT_SEQUENCE function to view the current value of a sequence generator.

10:05:42,141 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,141 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,141 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,141 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)

10:05:42,141 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    ... 58 more

10:05:42,142 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: ERROR X0Y84: Too much contention on sequence SERVING_LOCATION_SEQUENCE. This is probably caused by an uncommitted scan of the SYS.SYSSEQUENCES catalog. Do not query this catalog directly. Instead, use the SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_PEEK_AT_SEQUENCE function to view the current value of a sequence generator.

10:05:42,142 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,142 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseOpenQueryError(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,142 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseOPNQRYreply(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,142 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readOpenQuery(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,142 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readOpenQuery(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,142 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readOpenQuery_(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.readOpenQuery(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQueryX(Unknown Source)

10:05:42,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    ... 60 more
```

Entity class is as below:-

```
package rest.food.ordering.dbo;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="SERVING_LOCATION")
public class ServingLocationDBO {   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SER_LOC_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SER_LOC_SEQ", sequenceName = "SERVING_LOCATION_SEQUENCE",initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="LOCATION_ID",nullable = false)
    private BigInteger locationId;

    @Column(name="LOCATION_NAME",nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String locationName;

    public BigInteger getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(BigInteger locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public String getLocationName() {
        return locationName;
    }

    public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
        this.locationName = locationName;
    }
}
```

Do I need to manually create sequence into the DB as it is working fine with manually created sequence?

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: To gather full and complete information about the underlying cause of the exception, use these instructions: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Link in previous comment is dead.  Try this link instead (requires signing up for a free account on the Apache Confluence site): https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DERBY/UnwindExceptionChain

Answer (score -2):

hmmm, instead of GenerateType.SEQUENCE try GenerateType.AUTO. I think sequence is deprecated after hibernate 4. let me know if it worked.